# SQE plugin on Java EE project

Tags: netbeans-7, checkstyle, netbeans-plugins, java-ee-7

Upon importing a Java EE project, I can't seem to find any annotations regarding Code Quality. The option "Run All Quality Tools", "Run Findbugs", "Run Checkstyle" are disabled.

Is the SQE plugin not for a JavaEE project ? If so, is there an alternative ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Java EE project and I use the SQE plugin (in Netbeans 7.3.1).

The options "Run All Quality Tools", "Run Findbugs", "Run Checkstyle" are disabled as long as the project you want to check the quality for is not explicitly selected. That can e.g. be the case if you are in tab 'Files' instead of tab 'Projects'.

Comment: It's odd, I installed Checkstyle on it's own and it worked but SQE won't. It's disabled no matter what I do :(